# Swapping nodes in a linked list?

Tags: c, list, struct, linked-list

I wrote this function in order to swap 2 nodes in a linked list, but the result is a Segmentation Fault. Can you check it? Thanks.
(I did typedef for struct student* as punt)

```
void swap_node(punt node1, punt node2)
{

 node1->next=node2->next;
 node2->next=node1;
 node2->prev=node1->prev;
 node1->prev=node2;
 (node2->prev)->next=node2;

}
```

Comment: I think you should check for all the scenarios that might exist related to the positions and availability (null checks) of your nodes in the doubly linked list. Your question looks similar to this one (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20095529/swapping-nodes-in-double-linked-list)

Also if possible you can swap data of your nodes rather than the nodes themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this would be sufficient, basically the only difference from your code is the last statement (did not include null checks for simplicity):

```
void swap_node(punt node1, punt node2)
{

node1->next=node2->next;
node2->next=node1;
(node1->prev)->next=node2;
node2->prev=node1->prev;
node1->prev=node2;
(node1->next)->prev=node1;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When possible, two nodes are more easily swapped by only swapping their contents. The result is identical. This would pose a problem if somewhere else in your code you held a pointer to one of the nodes you swapped and are still expecting it to be the same node.

Anyway, back to your code. There are a few things that need refinement. Firstly, we need to check if `node1` and `node2` are not null and if they aren't we can proceed, otherwise exit the function as we can't swap this. The first 4 lines of your swapping code are alright, but here's two issues:

- Node that was before `node1` (prior to swapping) might be null, and thus accessing it's `next` pointer to point at `node2` would result in undefined behaviour and likely crash. Check if it exists and then perform the assignment.
- You forgot to check if there exists a node after `node2` (prior to swapping) and if so, point it's `prev` pointer at `node1`

Answer (score 0):

It usually helps to visualize the links in a doubly linked list, just draw it on a piece of paper. You'll notice 4 links per node:

```
node->next
node->next->prev
node->prev
node->prev->next
```

So to swap two unrelated nodes you need to *swap* the 4 links.

The following will not work:

```
node1->next=node2->next;
```

This overwrites the old value `node1-> next`. You need to use a temporary variable instead. Something like this:

```
#define SWAP_PTR(a,b) { void* tmp = b; b = a; a = tmp; }

void swap_node(punt node1, punt node2)
{
  SWAP_PTR(node1->next, node2->next);
  SWAP_PTR(node1->next->prev, node2->next->prev);
  SWAP_PTR(node1->prev, node2->prev);
  SWAP_PTR(node1->prev->next, node2->prev->next);
}
```

Note - in a threaded environment you'll need some form of locking.